# Find the sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-2)^k\frac{k+2}{k+1}x^k$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-2)^k\dfrac{k+2}{k+1}x^k.$$

I showed that this series converges when $|x|<\dfrac{1}{2}$ because $$\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|=2|x|.$$

Now I have to find the sum result. I tried so far trying to combine $$\ln(x+1)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^kx^{k+1}}{k+1}$$ and $$\arctan(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1},$$ and trying many substitutions with multiples of $x$, $x^2$ and got close to the result, but $\dfrac{k+2}{k+1}$ confuses me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would think of $(k+2)/(k+1)$ as $1 + 1/(k+1)$. Split the sum. Then you have $\sum (-2x)^k$ on the one hand (which you can handle) and $\sum (-2x)^k/(k+1)$, which might as well be $\sum (-y)^k/(k+1)$, which is $1/y$ times a natural log series.

Comment: Thanks! I tried hard stuff instead of dividing that trivial sum haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So we want to find the value of
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+2)(-2x)^k}{k+1}$$
As you already determined, we know
$$\ln (x+1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{k+1}}{k+1}$$
If you multiply both sides by $x$ you get
$$x\ln (x+1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{k+2}}{k+1}$$
Now, the *interesting step* is to take the derivative of both sides.
$$\ln (x+1)+\frac{x}{x+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+2}{k+1}(-1)^kx^{k+1}$$
Now divide both sides by $x$ to get
$$\frac{1}{x}\ln (x+1)+\frac{1}{x+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+2}{k+1}(-x)^k$$
Substitute $2x$ into $x$ to get,
$$\ln (2x+1)+\frac{1}{2x+1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+2}{k+1}(-2x)^k$$

Comment: What a nice approach! Thank you very much! :-) I'll select this as best answer, closed.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: observe that $\frac{k+2}{k+1} = 1+\frac{1}{k+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice this triviality.